# phonegap changing from port 3000

Tags: node.js, cordova

On the c9 IDE(c9.io) i installed node and phonegap globally, and started to build an app.

I can run the app on port 3000 by usign the command: `phonegap serve`

but i would like to run in a diferent port, using:

```
.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

that is the way to run node app on c9.io:
https://docs.c9.io/docs/writing-a-nodejs-app

I am having trouble to find the file to edit and change the port.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
phonegap serve -b $IP -p $PORT
```

thant is the command to run on c9